# CakePHP File utility doesn't find anything when the file's name has special characters

Tags: file, cakephp, character, directory

CakePHP File utility doesn't find anything when the file's name has special characters. For example `ñ` or `á`.

This is my helper:

```
public function ImageCompany($name = NULL, $url = NULL)
{
        $dir   = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'img/companies/');
        $files = $dir->find($name.'.png');
        if (isset($files[0])) {
            return $this->Html->link(
                            $this->Html->image('companies/'.$name.".png", array("alt" => $name)). '<br/> ' . __($name),
                            $url,
                            array('escape' => false)
                        );
        }else{
             return $this->Html->link(
                            $this->Html->image('companies/no-pre.png', array("alt" => $name)). '<br/> ' . __($name),
                            $url,
                            array('escape' => false)
                        );
        }
}
```

and even though I am pretty sure that the images exist, it doesn't display the image. But it works for all images without special characters on their name.